# Getting "undefined" email on Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-login

I was getting "undefined" email from my facebook API when trying to capture the user's email, so I made the following change due to the need to declare the fields I want.

old code:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name', function(response) {      
  console.debug(response);           
  fb_register(response);  
});
```

new code:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email,first_name,last_name'}, function(response) {      
  console.debug(response);           
  fb_register(response);  
});
```

But I still having the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ask the user for the necessary permission? And is the user's email verified (only then will it be returned)?